# Comparing two values in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to compare the below two values in choice connector and trying to catch the missing values from values from value 2 and value 1

Value1:

```
[
  {
    "FName": "salesforce.com"
  },
  {
    "FName": "jobs"
  },
  {
    "FName": "2020"
  },
  {
     "FName": "06-2020"   
  }
]
```

Value2:

```
[
  {
    "name": "salesforce.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "jobs"
  }
]
```

Am using choice condition vars.NameVar == vars.SplitName

I need to catch the values "FName": "2020" and "FName": "06-2020" which is missing in value 2

Comment: What relationship are between those variables (vars.NameVar, vars.SplitName) and this question? There is not a choice mentioned, and not data from those variables is used for your question. I think that them pertains to another question and can be removed from this one.

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var a=[
  {
    "FName": "salesforce.com"
  },
  {
    "FName": "jobs"
  },
  {
    "FName": "2020"
  },
  {
    "FName": "06-2020"   
  }
]
var b=[
  {
    "name": "salesforce.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "jobs"
  }
]
---
leftJoin(a, b, (x) -> x.FName, (x) -> x.name) 
    filter !$.r? 
        map $.l
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "FName": "2020"
  },
  {
    "FName": "06-2020"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for the logic, instead of hardcoding the varibles can i call like this

import * from dw::core::Arrays
vars.variableA
vars.varibaleB
---
leftJoin(variableA, variableA, (variableA) -> variableA.FName, (variableB) -> variableB.name) 
    filter !$.r? 
        map $.l

Comment: You can use any variable defined earlier in your mule flow in a dataweave script.  Reference like this `var.yourVariableName`

Comment: The script illustrates just the method. You can use an input from a variable or payload, as @shortstackstevens explained. The question is very confusing in what you mean. I changed the example to avoid using a and b where it is not needed. You just need to replace the only instances of a and b remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. This will only show the item that doesn't match from **value1** to **value2**

**Input:**

```
%dw 2.0
var value1=[
  {
    "FName": "salesforce.com"
  },
  {
    "FName": "jobs"
  },
  {
    "FName": "2020"
  },
  {
     "FName": "06-2020"   
  }
]
var value2=[
  {
    "name": "salesforce.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "jobs"
  }
]

output application/json
---
value1[?(!(value2.name contains $.FName))]
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "FName": "2020"
  },
  {
    "FName": "06-2020"
  }
]
```

The trick is to use the **contains** and the **! symbol**. If you remove the ***!*** it will reverse the logic, it will only display the matching values.